# NeoVim: How to copy current file including relative path into another project folder?

Tags: vim, neovim

Let's say I have two projects:

```
~/Dev/ProjectOne
~/Dev/ProjectTwo
```

My current directory is `~/Dev/ProjectOne`, and in the current buffer I have open:

`./app/controllers/spree/admin/some_controller.rb`

I want to copy this file into the same path in `~/Dev/ProjectTwo`:

`~/Dev/ProjectTwo/app/controllers/spree/admin/`

What is the shortest, most idomatic way to copy the current file into `~/Dev/ProjectTwo` while automatically expanding the relative path?

Of course it's possible to type out the whole copy command:

```
!cp ~/Dev/ProjectOne/app/controllers/spree/admin/some_controller.rb \
~/Dev/ProjectTwo/app/controllers/spree/admin
```

In nearly thirty years of Vim use, I can't believe I haven't thought of a better way!

Greatful for any ideas! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If the destination path exists, then you can simply do:

```
:w[rite] %:s/ProjectOne/ProjectTwo/
```

or:

```
:sav[eas] %:s/ProjectOne/ProjectTwo/
```

Where…

- `%` is the current filename,
- `:…` is a `:help filename-modifiers`,
- `:s/ProjectOne/ProjectTwo/` substitutes `ProjectOne` with `ProjectTwo` in the filename.

In practice, you might need to add more filename modifiers (like `:p` to make sure that you are working with the full absolute path). YMMV.

See `:help :w` and `:help :saveas` to decide which one to use.

--- EDIT ---

There is no "maximally generic solution". Not even in your shell, where `cp`, `mv`, `>`, and friends will throw errors left and right for non-existing paths.

In Vim, neither `:w` nor `:sav` are capable of writing a file to a non-existing path, which is something that must be done in two steps:

1. create the path if needed,
2. write the file.

That is relatively easy to script, mind you, and there are at least a couple of plugins for that, even. But it still requires *some* scripting… which pretty much means no "committing to permanent memory". See `:help mkdir()` for an equivalent of `$man mkdir`'s magnificent `-p`.

Alternatively, you could try `:help netrw` but I find it clunky as hell and, IIRC, it, too, is incapable of writing a file to a non-existing path anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the idea @romainl... What about if you want to make sure the target directory is created like a `mkdir -p`? 

What if the two paths are more different, like from `~/Dev/Project/SubProj` to `~/Dev/Other/Place`? 

Your answer is a totally valid response... I was just hoping for a maximally generic solution to commit to permeant memory that handles most permutations of the "move/copy from this project to that project" problem...

Comment: No "maximally generic solution" I'm afraid. See my edit.

Comment: You make a good point about how even in the shell this isn't really an easily solved problem... I suspect there is a shell plugin and a neovim or vim plugin that might address it though... In the next few days I'll try to search exhaustively for a plugin to help with this that we could add to your solution!